# Существует ли способ указать min-padding?

Tags: css

Существует ли способ указать min-padding?

Comment: Ну если подключить скрипт, то вполне возможно )

Answer (score 1):

Буквально именно свойства `min-padding` не существует, но желаемое поведение можно воссоздать обернув желаемый элемент контейнером, задав ему значение `padding`, которое должно быть минимальным. Также в некоторых случаях можно воcпрользоваться псевдоклассами `before` и/или `after`.

Answer (score 1):

**Нет, нету такого свойства**, хоть раньше и шли разговоры его добавить.

Нету (min/max) префиксов ни у `margin` ни у `padding`.

Вы можете попробовать достичь желаемого эффекта (в зависимости от задачи конечно) с помощью (`vh/vw`) величин.